# Best way to sync OMXPlayer video with audio stream?

Tags: audio, video, omxplayer, pulseaudio

I am having issues getting OMXPlayer video played on a TV via HDMI to sync with audio streamed over the network. My thought was delay the video output by ~500 ms then use pavucontrol to fine tune the audio to the TV and audio sink broadcast via udp to the network. I can't seem to find any way to actually delay the HDMI video, however. I tried just adjusting pavucontrol to have a negative delay but it doesn't adjusted anything (cant adjust audio if it hasn't been played yet). Am I going about this incorrectly?

If that isn't clear, here is a picture:

```
x axis = relative time ------------->


current setup:


          .----> sink to network ---------------> remote device
         /
        / 
       /
     .-------> audio to tv ------------>  
Pi  {                                    TV
     `-------> video to tv ------------>



desired outcome:


          .----> sink to network ---------------> remote device
         /
        / 
       /
    .-------> audio to tv ----(delay)----------->  
Pi {                                               TV
    `-------> video to tv ----(delay)----------->
```